# Unable to set label for sub-activity in android

Tags: android, label

Application starts from Activity2Activity.java and it is Calling Menu.java.
I m able to see the labels in Activity2Activity.java[Main Activity] but when it calls Other Activity Menu.java labels are not coming.

Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.firsttest.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MENU"
        android:label="ListMenu" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.firsttest.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity2Activity.java

```
public class Activity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent mainActivity = new Intent("com.firsttest.MENU");
                startActivity(mainActivity);
            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Menu.java

```
    public class MENU extends ListActivity{

    String classes[]={"Activity2Activity","TextPlay","Email","Camera","Data","example5"};
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        String cheese=classes[position];
        Class ourClass;
        try {
            ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.firsttest."+cheese);

        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MENU.this,ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("TagX", "Inside onCreate");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MENU.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show screenshots? Also, please notify me when you do so.

Comment: I m not allowed to put any images till i have 10 recommedations so tell me can i mail you?

Comment: Sure, virusofminds@gmail.com

Comment: I have mailed you please check

Comment: I checked. Replied you there as well.

Comment: I have send again.but i have checked even if i call MENU activity directly its still not displaying the label.

Comment: In the menu class you didn't setContentView() in the onCreate() method. I guess this is causing the trouble.

Comment: not working if you set setContentView...application gets crashed.If you have some code let me know.

Comment: I have understood the problem..i m not able to set ActionBar when ListActivity is used. any solution for this plz

Answer (score 0):

Set title in your menu.java file programatically.

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

OR

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: Force CLose is cming. LogCat Trace is                                                                       09-19 11:15:46.265: E/AndroidRuntime(31852): Process: com.example.firsttest, PID: 31852
09-19 11:15:46.265: E/AndroidRuntime(31852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firsttest/com.example.firsttest.MENU}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">  Try different theme. Such as Light or Holo. For single activity

Comment: Command is being executed successfully but neither Theme is changing nor any Lablel is coming.

Comment: Wanna add static header to listview? It same as actionbar. if yes then i gave u that code

Comment: please give i will try

Comment: Take one relativeLayout on top of your layout and add textview to it. <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/header"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:background="#FC9"
     android:gravity="center" >
     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:text="Fixed Header"
       android:textColor="#000"
       android:textSize="20sp" />
   </RelativeLayout>

Comment: I have understood the problem..i m not able to set ActionBar when ListActivity is used. any solution for this plz

Comment: please use Activity instead of ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); setContentView(R.layout.menu); 
this.setTitle("myclass2");
```

try this. Tell me if it works

Comment: Force Close again09-19 11:25:43.205: E/AndroidRuntime(699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firsttest/com.example.firsttest.MENU}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
09-19 11:25:43.205: E/AndroidRuntime(699): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
09-19 11:25:43.205: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:381)

Comment: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MENU.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));                               this is already setting one layout..Could this be the problem?